# Why is `=0D\r\n` Appearing in my Email Scraping using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, imap

I'm using `imaplib` to retrieve emails from Gmail to feed into `Beautifulsoup` to parse the email's HTML code.

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
M.select('Inbox')
rv, data = M.SEARCH(None, '(FROM "foo@bar.com")')
if rv == 'OK':
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        html = data[0][1].strip()
```

**Question:** Why does `html` contains so many occurrences of `=0D\r\n`? What are they and should we remove them completely or replace them with another string?

**Example:**

```
<td class=3D"width10T hide" align=3D"right"=\r\n=0D\r\nwidth=3D"31"></td>=0D\r\n                            </tr>=0D\r\n
```

---

***Update***

Tried parsing as `quoted-printible` using

```
html = html.decode('utf-8')
html = email.message_from_string(html)
```

which cleaned up `html` a lot better, but there are still traces of `=0D` at the end of almost every line. How can we fix this?

There's also strings `3D` that occur after `=`...

```
</tr>=0D
<tr>=0D
    <td height=3D"12"></td>=0D
</tr>=0D
<tr></tr>=0D
<tr>=0D
    <td class=3D"height35" height=3D"50"></td>=0D
</tr>=0D
</tbody>=0D
```

Comment: You're not decoding the email body properly before trying to parse it as HTML; that's `quoted-printable` (RFC1521 5.1) encoding.

Comment: @hobbs Thanks, tried using `email.message_from_string(html)` and `.decode('utf-8')` to parse it but there are still remains of `=0D`. Updated original post.

Comment: You said you "Tried parsing as quoted-printible...", but I don't see any evidence of that?

Comment: @larsks Using `quopri.decodestring(html)` did the trick.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I didn't see in your question :).